# Is the proximity sensor a private api?

Tags: ios, api, proximity

Apple documents the proximity sensor [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html), so I would imagine it's a public api. I have heard otherwise and wanted to double check before submitting to the store.

Comment: rule of thumb is that, if the document is publicly available, is not a private API. API's like springboard and others are completely private, and you will only find documentations from third party available for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It used to be the case that the proximity sensor was a private API, but after quite a bit of outcry, Apple made it a public API.

With the `UIDevice` API, you're able to query the proximity sensor for your needs, as documented in the link you've provided.